# how can i load a dll and assign routing url to methods to use them as webAPI calls?

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

i'm writing an application in asp.net core with a set of webAPI defined usig MVC and routing attributes.
Now i'd like to manage additionals functions but, as a plugin, i'm going to define them in a external DLL and  then load it with

```
Assembly assemblyPlugin = Assembly.LoadFrom(DLL2load);
```

This is ok but how can i be able to call its methods as webAPI from anotther application ?
May i have to define their routing attributes inside the loaded DLL or to assign them after loading it in the main application? How can i do it ?

Comment: You call this api method via reflection, Why you need to consider the `route attribute` in web api application?

Answer (score 0):

you can do following,

```
services.AddControllers() // use AddControllersWithViews for MVC app
        .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("DlltoLoad")));
```

Comment: Thank you CodingMytra. This way, inserted in ConfigureServices, the Dll is directly loaded and available, with all routing methods defined in it.
But now, if i have more than one DLL to load but number and names are not kown in advance, can i add their fullname in a specific part of appsettings.json to read them and loop your instruction to load all at starting time ?  or how ?

Comment: Yes it possible.

Comment: Sorry, now how to call a function from the imported DLL?

Comment: @CodingMytra, can I ask about the case when the the dll is loaded during runtime (as a plugin) ? how to refresh the AddControllers services to get access to the new WEB API endpoints (the endpoints are accessible only after server restart) ? tried to look around about a clear answer but without success, Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is way to just replace the dll and expect that it will load during runtime. in this case dll gets loaded on startup so you need to restart your server to take the effect of the newly replaced dll.